# Select query to get tags per post_id

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-by

I am trying to make simple mysql select query, I have 3 tables

```
post: post_id...
tags: tag_id, tag_name
post_tag: id_post, id_tag
```

and I wrote this query:

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from post 
LEFT JOIN post_tag 
ON post_tag.id_post = post.post_id
LEFT JOIN tags
ON post_tag.id_tag = tags.tag_id    
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY post_id 
DESC LIMIT 5");
```

but I am getting only one tag per post even there is more tags with same post_id?

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
{
  $post_id =$row['post_id '];           
  $tag_name=$row['tag_name'];

  echo $post_id $tag_name;
}
```

Comment: That is because you group by post_id

Comment: yep, otherwise it will print "post" for each tag?

Comment: Then you will probably need something like GROUP_CONCAT, to aggregate the values of all the tags. [added an answer with a suggestion for your query]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
SELECT post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_name) AS tag_name FROM post 
LEFT JOIN post_tag 
ON post_tag.id_post = post.post_id
LEFT JOIN tags
ON post_tag.id_tag = tags.tag_id    
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY post_id 
DESC LIMIT 5
```

This will give you one record for each post with a comma seperated list of every tagname that is linked to that post.

Comment: I can't make it works, I am still getting only one tag pro post

Comment: I updated the query in my answer (I gave the GROUP_CONCAT() an alias, so that you will be able to use it)

Comment: you are the men, thank you very much it's works as expected. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your query is grouping by post_id.  In other databases, this would cause an error.  In MySQL this is considered a feature called hidden columns.

The values that you get are not guaranteed to come from the same row (although in practice  think they do).  You probaly want something like:

```
select *
from post LEFT JOIN
     post_tag 
     ON post_tag.id_post = post.post_id LEFT JOIN
     tags
     ON post_tag.id_tag = tags.tag_id    
ORDER BY post_id 
DESC LIMIT 5
```

However, if you just want the tags on a post, you might consider using gruop_concat:

```
select post_id, group_concat(tag.tag_name separator ',') as tags
from post LEFT JOIN
     post_tag 
     ON post_tag.id_post = post.post_id LEFT JOIN
     tags
     ON post_tag.id_tag = tags.tag_id
group by post_id
```